# Hangman: How do you reveal letters when they are guessed?

Tags: java

I am creating a hangman program in java. The program is supposed to randomly generate the word and as the user correctly guesses a letter it should reveal it. I have created the function where it prints the amount of underscores depending on the length of the word. The issue I have is I'm not sure how I'm supposed to replace the underscore with the letter when it's guessed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice;
    String wordSoFar = "";

        Console.print("Take your time.");
        choice = Console.readInt("Enter your choice, when you're ready : ");

    }

    if (choice == 1) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            word += " _ ";
        }

        do {
            String guess = Console.readString("Enter your guess here : ");
            String response = secert(guess);
            Console.print(response);
        } while (incorrectLetters < maxIncorectLetters || correctLetters < wordLength);
    }
}

public static String secretWordSelector(String secretWord) {
    String[] secretWordsList = { "fun", "boring", "yellow", "phython", "tesla", "iphone", "computer", "adventure",
             };
    int min = 0;
    int max = 8;

    secretWord = secretWordsList[randomNumber(min, max)];

    return secretWord;

}
public static String letterChecker(String guess, String wordSoFar) {
    String response = "";
    String secertWord = "";
    if (secretWord == guess)) {
        int index = secretWord.indexOf(guess);
        correctLetters++;
        answer = "Congratulations!
            
    } else  {
        answer= "That is a incorrect guess! 
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: have a look at String.replaceAll() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) it might come in handy! But you are not far off I think. Solve it with a pen and paper first then fix you java program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be improved a lot by the following changes:

1. You do not need the complex function, `randomNumber`. You can simply pass the length of the array to [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) and it will generate an `int` in the range of `0` to `length_of_array - 1`.
2. Similarly, your function, `length` is not required. You can simply call [`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) to get the length of the string.
3. You have unnecessarily passed an argument to your function, `secretWordSelector`.
4. Since you are using `String wordSoFar` in multiple methods, it will be easier to process it by making it global.
5. You have called `secretWordSelector` again in `letterChecker` which is wrong. You have to process the same word which was selected randomly at the time when the user selected a choice.
6. Your `while` loop is infinite because of the wrong operator. It should be `while (incorrectLetters < maxIncorectLetters && correctLetters < wordLength)`
7. I have re-written the method, `letterChecker` with many changes which are self-explanatory. I have also put some comments to help you understand its code easily.

**Code incorporating these improvements:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static int incorrectLetters;
    private static int correctLetters;
    private static String wordSoFar = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int maxIncorectLetters = 6;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mahmoud's Hangman game!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to play. 1 - Yes. 0 - No");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if (choice == 0) {
            System.out.println("Take your time.");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice, when you're ready: ");
            choice = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Be careful, you can only have 6 wrong guesses");
            int wordLength = 0;
            String secretWord = secretWordSelector();
            wordLength = secretWord.length();
            System.out.println("Your word has " + wordLength + " letters.");
            for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
                wordSoFar += "_";
            }

            do {
                System.out.print("Enter your guess here: ");
                String guess = scanner.nextLine();
                String response = letterChecker(guess.toLowerCase().charAt(0), secretWord);
                System.out.println(response);
            } while (incorrectLetters < maxIncorectLetters && correctLetters < wordLength);
        }
    }

    public static String secretWordSelector() {
        String[] secretWordsList = { "geography", "cat", "yesterday", "java", "truck", "opportunity", "fish", "token",
                "transportation", "bottom", "apple", "cake", "remote", "boots", "terminology", "arm", "cranberry",
                "tool", "caterpillar", "spoon", "watermelon", "laptop", "toe", "toad", "fundamental", "capitol",
                "garbage", "anticipate", "pesky" };

        return secretWordsList[new Random().nextInt(secretWordsList.length)];
    }

    public static String letterChecker(char guess, String secretWord) {
        String response = "";

        // Initialize a StringBuilder with wordSoFar
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordSoFar);

        if (secretWord.indexOf(guess) != -1) {// i.e. if guess is present in secretWord
            // Replace each corresponding occurrence of '_' in the StringBuilder with guess
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
                char ch = secretWord.charAt(i);
                if (ch == guess) {
                    sb.setCharAt(i, ch);
                    correctLetters++;
                }
            }
            // Assign the updated StringBuilder to wordSoFar
            wordSoFar = sb.toString();
            return "Congratulations! You have guessed correctly. " + " You have " + incorrectLetters
                    + " incorrect guesses " + wordSoFar;
        }
        incorrectLetters++;
        response = "That is a incorrect guess! " + " You have " + incorrectLetters + " incorrect guesses " + wordSoFar;

        return response;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to Mahmoud's Hangman game!
Would you like to play. 1 - Yes. 0 - No
Enter your choice: 1
Be careful, you can only have 6 wrong guesses
Your word has 4 letters.
Enter your guess here: o
That is a incorrect guess!  You have 1 incorrect guesses ____
Enter your guess here: e
That is a incorrect guess!  You have 2 incorrect guesses ____
Enter your guess here: a
That is a incorrect guess!  You have 3 incorrect guesses ____
Enter your guess here: h
Congratulations! You have guessed correctly.  You have 3 incorrect guesses ___h
Enter your guess here: f
Congratulations! You have guessed correctly.  You have 3 incorrect guesses f__h
Enter your guess here: i
Congratulations! You have guessed correctly.  You have 3 incorrect guesses fi_h
Enter your guess here: s
Congratulations! You have guessed correctly.  You have 3 incorrect guesses fish
```